# Can I use a neural network on a linear regression using Keras? If yes , How?

Tags: python-2.7, neural-network, theano, keras-layer

I'm having difficulties setting up a NN in Keras. Please help me!

This is my code and I'm getting random values every time when I predict.

```
model = Sequential()
layer1 = Dense(5, input_shape = (5,))
model.add(layer1)
model.add(Activation('relu'))

layer2 = Dense(1)
model.add(layer2)   
model.add(Activation('relu'))


model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, verbose=1)
```

I have 5 input features and want to predict a single continuous value as an output

Comment: What do the contents of `xtrain` and `ytrain` look like?

Comment: It is an array of array. xtrain have shape (93,6) and ytrain have shape (93,1)

Answer (score 1):

Input space have five features.
The problem was that i am getting random prediction at same input. Now, I have reach the solution. It is happening just because of that i am not doing the normalisation of features.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view,

you are not giving your input shape correctly

```
layer1 = Dense(5, input_shape = (5,))
```

What is your actual input shape?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Input space have five features.